# How does mzero match guard type signature?

Tags: haskell, monads, alternative-functor, monadplus

I have trouble understanding how `guard` works. Why does it type check? Isn't `mzero` capable of returning some `m a` where `a /= ()`?

```
guard           :: (MonadPlus m) => Bool -> m ()
guard True      =  return ()
guard False     =  mzero

mzero :: m a
```

Comment: Incidentally, there's no such thing as _type inequality_ in Haskell. There's just type equality `a ~ ()`, and like with all constraints, it is assumed that this could in principle be true even if the compiler can't proove it – so you can never negate constraints. In fact is _is_ true here, `a ~ ()` is precisely what the compiler infers for that `mzero`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `mzero` *is* capable of returning some `m a` where `a /= ()`. But it's also capable of returning `m ()`. `guard` uses it in this second case.

It's similar to this:

```
n :: Int
n = 5
```

`5` can be a `Float` or `Double`, but can also be an `Int`. The compiler chooses the needed interpretation of `5` during type checking.

Similarly, the compiler chooses the right type for `mzero` in the original example during type checking. More precisely, it sees that a `m ()` is needed, so it chooses that type.

The important bit here is that

```
mzero :: MonadPlus m => m a
```

actually means

```
mzero :: forall m a . MonadPlus m => m a
```

which states that the *caller* of `mzero` gets to choose the actual values for `m` and `a` (as long as `m` is a `MonadPlus`). Hence, the caller can choose `a=()` to make things type check. This choice can be made by the user through a type annotation, otherwise the compiler will try to *infer* the correct choice during type checking.